# How to redirect on a app from a -in app- button

Tags: android

is it possible to press a button and start a call e.x. in skype?(i know that is possible for a telephone call but i would like to see if i can make this stuff with a voip app as skype)

Answer (score 1):

If the user has skype installed, and the user tries to place a call there are two options you can take:

i.e. just try and call skype directly (but this requires knowing the correct intent to launch skype) or you request to make a call and the user will be shown the option to use skype to place the call (unless they've set the default dialer and the primary application).

I think there may be a way to get a list of activities that are registered to handle certain events (i.e. get the list of dialler apps on the device) from this you might be able to find the skype app and get enough information to force the use of that. The problem with this is you are then tied into using skype and only skype rather than let the platform handle it.